# Number of questions i have about improving my quality of coding:

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Hope it's not against rules to post more than 1 question per page.

1. I have value1, which changes based on value2 changing. And because of that, every time i change value2, i go [self changeValue1] and then that runs some code which looks at value2 and changes value1. Is there a more automated way of doing this, where i can have the app be notified when value2 changes and calls such a method?
2. I have methods (such as the one above) that i don't want to be accessed from outside that class. How do i make a method private?

Comment: Sounds like the work of a delegate to me.

Comment: It's probably better to just ask one question at the time next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ad 1. Look for Key Value Observing in the documents.

ad 2. Define the methods in a private category. This doesn't mean other classes can't call the method anymore, but at least you'll be warned about it by the compiler.

In your MySubclass.m:

```
@interface MySubclass ()

- (void)myPrivateMethod;

@end

@implementation MySubclass 

etc. etc.
```

Answer (score 1):

For Question 1, you can see Key Value Observing: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/KeyValueObserving/KeyValueObserving.html

For question 2, you can add an extension of the class at the top of your .m file with the method to add

```
@interface MyClass ()

-(void) _myPrivateMethod;

@end
```

Comment: What's the difference between having a _ at the start, and not having one?

Comment: it's just a naming convension to know that this method is private

Comment: Methods (and variable) names starting with an underscore are reserved by Apple. If anything make it a trailing underscore, but I generally don't see the need for this. The fact that a method is only defined in the private category makes its intent clear enough.

Comment: @Johan: Marking the name of the method makes it easier to see that it's private _at the call site_.